# "Next" button not disappearing in app when it's supposed to

Tags: ios, swift

Shown below is the code that I am using to get my next button to disappear. However the button does not disappear.

```
 func nextPage() {
    //we are on the last page
    if pageControl.currentPage == pages.count {
        moveControlConstraintsOffScreen()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    //second last page
    if pageControl.currentPage == pages.count {
       return
    }

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: pageControl.currentPage + 1, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    pageControl.currentPage += 1
}
```

Comment: Where is your button in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your link, it seems like you are adding your `nextButton` to `view`. You need to call this method to make it disappear.

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(nextButton)
```